# HashMap has containsValue method, but not getValue method

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, java-7

I am curious that in the Java collections library, **HashMap** has a method that searches for the existance of a particular *object value* called ***containsValue(Object value)*** returing a ***boolean***, but no method exists to *get* the **value object** by ***value object*** directly like you do by providing a *key* via the *get(Object key)* method.  Now, I know that the purpose of *HashMap* is to access object values via the keys, but in exceptional cases may want retrieve via the *object value*, so why is there not a *getValue(Object value)* method?  I ask this, because the algorithm that the method ***containsValue()*** implements to search for the ***object value*** is faster than my custom search (*see below*).  Also, is there a better way to accomplish this search using **HashMap** in Java 7 ?

Code Snippet:

```
// Custom Search
MyCustomer findCust = new MyCustomer(50000, "Joe Bloggs", "London");
for (MyCustomer value : hashMap.values()) {

    if (value.equals(findCust)) { // found
            cust = value;
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you already have the value, what would you be getting?

Comment: Is the point that the one in the map has additional data on it (which is obviously not taken into account by the `hashCode` and `equals` methods) which is not present on the one you are searching by? Because otherwise this seems completely pointless. Why not just write `cust = findCust`?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Good point,  I am just playing with collections at present and was trying to match the speed of retrieving the _object value_ as the _containValue()_ method does.  Hence, changing my question a little, is the code that I provided for iterating a HashMap collection in Java 7 the best way (without resorting to completed algorithms)?  For example, instead of writing _if (value.equals(findCust))_ to replace it with _if (value.getXXX().equals(criteria))_ to get the _object value_ matching my criteria, is the code okay or would you recommend to write it another way? Thanks

Comment: I am thinking that if you have an object that is equal in value (same field values) as an object in the HashMap, and you want to compare them by value, the `containsValue()`, `containsKey()` and `get(key` should provide all functionality needed.  If you have additional fields which are not accounted for with `equals()` or `hashcode()`, it would then depend on your additional code to utilize the additional functionality.

Comment: I also wonder when would be a case where you need to iterate over each element in a HashMap to check for an object by value when they have built in methods where you would not have access to a key value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic assumption of the collections framework is that if two objects are `.equals`, they are interchangeable in every way.  Given that assumption, there's no reason to get out the value from a `Map`, because you already have one that is `equals` and interchangeable.  As far as the Collections Framework is concerned, these two methods are fully equivalent:

```
for (V value : map.values()) {
  if (value.equals(myValue)) {
    return value;
  }
}
```

and

```
if (map.containsValue(myValue)) {
  return myValue;
}
```

This assumption is built into the Collections Framework in many places, and this is one of many examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually I was playing with collections and trying to match the speed of retrieving the _object value_ as the _containValue()_ method does. Hence, regarding 2nd part of my question, is the code that I provided for iterating a _HashMap_ collection in Java 7 the best way (without resorting to completed algorithms)? E.g, in the provided code I could replace _if (value.equals(findCust))_ with _if (value.getXXX().equals(criteria))_ to get the _object value_ matching my criteria, is the code okay or would you recommend to write it another way? Thanks

Comment: In Java 7, you have the best way to do it already; there won't be a better way.  In Java 8, you _might_ be able to do better by writing `map.values().stream().filter(value -> value.getXXX().equals(criteria)).findAny()`, and you could parallelize that using `parallelStream()`.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't have enough reputations to up vote your answer, but I have ticked it.

Answer (score 0):

```
hashMap.values().contains(findCust)
```

You will need equals and hashCode on Customer based on your "business rules" (for example, are two customers with the same "id" but with different other values "equal"????... Obviously you are already doing that because you are using equals...)

Comment: You have **not** read my question properly (and yes, I have already overriden the _equals()_ and _hashCode()_ methods and my code works).  My question was why is there **not** a _getValue()_ method and if my provided code could be written in a more efficient way?  If it was you who down voted my question, please reverse it.  Thanks.

Comment: Ps. In additional to my above comment, the code you provided is long winded, the shortcut is using directly _containsValue()_ method directly in **HashMap** as both return a **boolean**.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is designed to aid constant lookups using `hashcode()` and `equals()` of the key you use to put some value into map.

If you look at the internal structure of HashMap, it's nothing but an array. Each index is called a bucket which can be obtained by normalizing current array's length and the hashcode of the key you pass. Once you find the bucket, it will store the element at that particular index. But if there's already some element stored in that index, they will form a LinkedList of these elements chaining all the values having same `hashcode()` but different `equals()` criteria.

In Java 8, this linked list is even changed to TreeMap if the number of elements in that linked list reaches some threshold (8) for improving performance.

Coming to your question, `containsValue()` basically iterates over all the buckets in the array and again through all the elements in the linked list of each bucket

```
// iterate through buckets
for (int i = 0; i < table.length; ++i) {

      // iterate through each element in linked list at each bucket
      for (Node<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
              if ((v = e.value) == value ||
                      (value != null && value.equals(v)))
                   return true;
      }
 }
```

`HashMap.values()` returns a Collection with the iterator implemented to traverse each element in HashMap providing access to `Value` object in each iteration.

`containsValue()` is used when you want to do something if some value is already there in the map but you don't need that value to proceed with your flow.This is merely a convenience method because if you're using `values`, you will be creating a Collection object and an iterator object to iterate over them but using `containsValue()`, you just have two nested for loops. I think the reason for not having a `getValue()` is to encourage the purpose HashMap is intended for - near constant time look ups using hashcode & equals of some key.

`values()` is used when you basically need to iterate over all the values. This is different from calling `map.get(key)` in a loop because you don't have to normalize the hashcode, find the bucket, then find the element in the linked list in each iteration, you just loop in the natural order, the way the elements are laid out in the array.

If you're doing this value lookup way too many times, you lose the advantage of constant lookups offered by HashMap. If you're only going to skim through the values searching for some value, I suggest you use an `ArrayList`. If there are too many elements in that list, and you need to search for some random value quite often, sort the list and use Binary Search.